# Pandas lambda function raised an indexing error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, lambda

I have a data frame df and would like to reassign value from columns b to the last columns. The logic is as follows: if "b" column value is greater or equal to the previous row of "a" column value, reassign "b" value as "green", otherwise "red". My code raise an indexing error: Too many indexers. Have no idea what's wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
value = [[10, 95, 10, 32],[22, 12, 3, 15],[28, 25, 5, 29],[30, 11, 66, 16]]
df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

for j in range(2, len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:,j] = df.apply(lambda x: "green" if x.iloc[:,j] >= (x["b"].shift(periods = 1)) else "red", axis = 1)
```

The expected result is:

```
 a     b     c     d

10   nan   nan   nan
22  green  red   green
28  green  red   green
30  red   green  red
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the logic. Are all columns compared to `a`? if so wouldn't the last row of C be green as 66 >= 28? Can you elaborate on why the expected values are expected?

Comment: Specifically the issue is that `x` is a Series and only has a single dimension. So it would be something like `x.iloc[j]` but then you'll have other errors raised.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you Henry. I don't understand why x here is a Series. I applied lambda function on df, isn't x referring to the data frame df?

Comment: So `x` is referring to a _row_ (axis=1) of the DataFrame. Which is a single dimension (Series), not two-dimensional data like a DataFrame.

Comment: Good to know it. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and compare where the columns are [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) than the [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) of `a`:

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].ge(df['a'].shift(), axis=0),
                          'green',
                          'red')
df.iloc[0, 1:] = np.nan
```

`df`:

```
    a      b      c      d
0  10    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  22  green    red  green
2  28  green    red  green
3  30    red  green    red
```

The second assignment to put the nans back in the first row is necessary as nan >= value is `False` so the first row will end up all `red`.

---

It may be beneficial to add the `NaN` values back based on where the the shifted series is `NaN` (this allows for different types of shifting, but will not change the output from the above)

```
s = df['a'].shift()
df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].ge(s, axis=0), 'green', 'red')
df.iloc[s.isna(), 1:] = np.nan
```

---

A (slower) option with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df['a'].shift()
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(
    lambda x: x.ge(s).map({True: 'green', False: 'red'})
)
df.iloc[s.isna(), 1:] = np.nan
```

---

Or `apply` + `np.where`:

```
s = df['a'].shift()
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(
    lambda x: np.where(x.ge(s), 'green', 'red')
)
df.iloc[s.isna(), 1:] = np.nan
```